# Conditional dropdown color not working in mobile

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown where I have conditionaly rendered the color of the dropdown options.

```
<option className={bookingCount >=bookingLimit ? 'bg-danger' : 'bg-success'}>
name
</option>
```

It works on desktop browser but no color is shown on mobile browsing.

Comment: Does it only appear for those two colors or for all className?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: Any online example, and your browser version of your mobile device?

Comment: my mobile chrome version 80.0.3987.119